# Homestead PHP 7.3 php.ini - unable to disable deprecated warnings

Tags: php, error-handling, homestead, error-reporting

I am running a Zend 1.x application on PHP 7.3 with Homestead/Vagrant and I get a number of deprecated warnings - I have tried to disable these but nothing seems to 'hide' the deprecated warnings - I have added the following in the php.ini and restarted fpm & apache but I still keep seeing these errors in the browser.

// php.ini error_reporting

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED`

// This is the error I see in the browser

`Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated....`

Comment: If at all possible try to get an updated version of the application (or update it yourself if its your own code!).  Failing that, you might be better off running it against an older version of PHP in something like a docker container.  At least that way it'll be isolated from the more modern code

Comment: Don't hide errors, fix them!

Comment: @Dharman you are right however for this particular purpose as we quite a lot of deprecated functionality in this legacy app I just need to hide them for now but I do generally agree with you